# How can I write the Taylor Series for e^x using map and reduce functions in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I need some help with writing the Taylor Series of e^x in Python. However, I am quite limited to the kind of functions I can use:

- map
- reduce
- range
- factorial
- 'helper' functions written by yourself

Any pointers or help would be much appreciated. I am trying to get to know more about Python in general as well.

This is what I have so far in terms of code:

```
def taylorApproxE(lastIter):
    '''approximates the value of e using Taylor Series.'''
    L = range(lastIter + 1)

    def sum(x,y):
        return x + y

    def iter(x,y):
        return (x**y)/factorial(y)

    return reduce(sum, map(iter, L))
```

Every time I attempt to use this function in my terminal, I get

`TypeError: iter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'`

For those who don't know what a Taylor Series is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

But basically I'm taking the sum as shown here:
[Taylor Series for e^x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arnlV.png)

What should happen when I use the function is

```
taylorApproxE(4) = 2.708333333333333
```

Edit: I apologize for not being clear enough in the first draft of this question. I am extremely new to this website and have not been well-accustomed to the rules of posting. I hope I did not offend with my transgressions in formatting or phrasing.

Comment: Good idea, go ahead get started, you will learn something!

Comment: @rdacier, Stack is a site for questions and answers.  Your post does not have an actual question, it looks like you're asking people to write code for you.  That won't do...  If you want  help, here's some tips: 1 - try to write some code; if that does not work, post it with a specific question on the point that is not working; 2 - not everybody knows what a 'Taylor series' is, including many people that would be otherwise willing to help.  Add a link to the Wikipedia article on that, and write a quick summary of what it is.  Good luck

Comment: You have defined "iter" to be a function of two arguments, but in the expression "map( iter, L )" you have provided only one input.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code with one or two parameters:

for example:

`taylorApproxE(4) = 2.708333333333333` (e for 4+1 terms)

`taylorApproxE(4,2) = 7` (e^2 for 4+1 terms)

```
from math import factorial
from functools import reduce

def taylorApproxE(lastIter, x_in=1):
    n_range = range(lastIter + 1)
    return reduce(lambda y, z: y + z, map(lambda x: x_in ** x / factorial(x), n_range))


print(taylorApproxE(4))
```